# How to make a like query to @ElementCollection of type map?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have a class like this:

```
class MyEntity {
    @ElementCollection
    Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

I'd like to find out which MyEntity entities have a property value that matches `like` query using the criteria API. By this I mean I'd like to make a `like` query on the values of the map entries.

For example if one of my MyEntity classes has a property named "email" and the value is "example@mail.com", how do I make a query that finds the entity with a query parameter "example%" using criteria API?

Comment: AFAIL Criteria API do not supports something similar to HQL's `properties['email']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. There is a joinMap(String) method in Path API which can be used in this case:

```
builder.like(
    root.<MyEntity, String, String>joinMap("properties").value(), "example%");
```

That piece of code will create a `like` predicate against the values of the properties map. This would probably been easier to find out if I had generated the MetaModel of the MyEntity...