# How to query for entities by their collection value

Tags: jpa, collections, criteria-api

I'm using jpa and I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="favorites_folders")
public class FavoritesFolder {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     private String id;

     @NotNull
     @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
     public String name;

     @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @CollectionTable(
        name="favorites_products",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="folder_id")
        )
     @Column(name="product_id")
     @NotNull
     private Set<String> productsIds = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

What I want to do is to get a set of `FavoritesFolder` entities that contains the string "favorite-id" in their `productsIds` member set.

Does anyone know how can it be done in **criteria api**?

**Update:**
I'm thinking the following sql should do the trick but I'm not sure how to do it in either `JPQL` or `Criteria API`:

```
select * from favorites_folders join favorites_products on favorites_folders.id = favorites_products.folder_id where favorites_products.product_id = 'favorite-id'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get a set of FavoritesFolder entities that contains the string "favorite-id" in their productsIds member set using criteria api you should do the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder(); //em is EntityManager
CriteriaQuery<FavoritesFolder> cq = cb.createQuery(FavoritesFolder.class);
Root<FavoritesFolder> root = cq.from(FavoritesFolder.class);

Expression<Collection<String>> productIds = root.get("productsIds");
Predicate containsFavoritedProduct = cb.isMember("favorite-id", productIds);

cq.where(containsFavoritedProduct);

List<FavoritesFolder> favoritesFolders = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

More information on [Collections in JPQL and Criteria Queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection).

Comment: I know in this topic we are reffering to ID's and therefore they have to be EQUAL to match, but let's say we have a `Collection<String>` instead, can we do essentially the same thing but instead of needing an item to be `equal`, we could have an item MATCH using `LIKE` ?

Comment: @dominicbri7 on a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066122/how-to-make-a-like-query-to-elementcollection-of-type-map?rq=1) I found the solution. Use the join method on Root class `cb.like(from.join("apples").get("color"), textParameter)`

Answer (score 2):

Just another way using IN

```
@Entity
public class UserCategory implements Serializable {
private static final long    serialVersionUID    = 8261676013650495854L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ElementCollection
private List<String> categoryName;


(...)
}
```

Then you can write a Criteria query like

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserCategory> q = cb.createQuery(UserCategory.class);
    Root<UserCategory> root = q.from(UserCategory.class);

    Predicate predicate = cb.conjunction();
    Predicate p1 = cb.equal(root.get(UserCategory_.targetSiteType), siteType.getName());
    Predicate p2 = root.get(UserCategory_.categoryName).in(category);
    predicate = cb.and(p1,p2);

    q.where(predicate);

    TypedQuery<UserCategory> tq = entityManager.createQuery(q);
    List<UserCategory> all = tq.getResultList();

    if (all == null || all.size() == 0){
        return null;
    }else if (all.size() > 1){
        throw new Exception("Unexpected result - "+all.size());
    }else{
        return all.get(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around that works.
I'm using Springboot 1.5.9. I don't have time to identify the root cause. What I know is such nested property been ignored when get through `JacksonMappingAwareSortTranslator`.
So what I did to workaround this is not to use Sort object created by resolvers.
Here's my code in `Kotlin`. Without doing this, the `pageable.sort` is `null` and sorting does not work. And my code will create a new `PageRequest` object that has non-null `sort` that works.

```
    @RequestMapping("/searchAds", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
    fun searchAds(
        @RequestBody cmd: AdsSearchCommand,
        pageable: Pageable,
        resourceAssembler: PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,
        sort: String? = null
    ): ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<Ads>>> {
        val page = adsService.searchAds(cmd, pageable.repairSortIfNeeded(sort))
        resourceAssembler as ResourceAssembler<Ads, Resource<Ads>>
        return adsPagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(page, resourceAssembler).toResponseEntity()
    }

    fun Pageable.repairSortIfNeeded(sort: String?): Pageable {
        return if (sort.isNullOrEmpty() || this.sort != null) {
            this
        } else {
            sort as String
            val sa = sort.split(",")
            val direction = if (sa.size > 1) Sort.Direction.valueOf(sa[1]) else Sort.Direction.ASC
            val property = sa[0]
            PageRequest(this.pageNumber, this.pageSize, direction, property)
        }
    }
```